# Trying to write Haskell function to take string parameter and append to file

Tags: haskell, io

I am trying to write a function that takes a string as input and appends it to a file. the file is the same file every time. the function compiles correctly but gives the error

"No instance for (Show (String -> IO ()))
        arising from a use of `print'".

The code is:

```
appendText :: String -> IO ()

appendText [] = return ()

appendText x = appendFile "testfile.txt" x
```

I understand the problem is something to do with types and the Show type but I'm having trouble understanding the problem and how to correct it. Any help would be great.

Edit: I am calling it as a function, e.g. appendFile "random text"

Comment: You'll need to show enough of the program (and the way you are using it) to include the part that generates the error, which you are not currently doing. Specifically, none of your code includes the use of `print` that is causing the error. Try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, please try to use the code formatting tools. Indentation in Haskell is significant and it may be impossible to know whether your code is correct without seeing how it is actually indented. I've gone ahead and done this for you this time.

Comment: To clarify, there is no use of "print" in my program, that's why the error confused me. The code I have included is completely isolated from any other code in the program.

Answer (score 2):

Did you attempt to write something like `appendText` or `print appendText` in GHCi? If so, it’s attempting to `Show` the function, which is a type error since function types don’t have a `Show` instance. You need to invoke it with an argument, being the particular `String` that you want to append to `testfile.txt`:

```
appendText "test text"
```

The type of this is `IO ()`, so it’s an action that can be executed, and after running it you ought to see the text appear in the file.

Your function can also be written more simply as:

```
appendText x = appendFile "testfile.txt" x
```

Or in point-free form:

```
appendText = appendFile "testfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

So to be clear, removing the second line allowed the function to work:

appendText :: String -> IO ()

appendText = appendFile "testfile.txt"

I'm not sure why this fixed the problem, that line was there for error handling purposes but apparently wasn't needed. It works though, thanks for the help.